# What does this command mean in batch?

Tags: file, batch-file, dos

I'm looking at a batch file and I see the line below. I know what %LOG% is, but I do not know what the "rm" command is doing. Can anyone tell me?

```
rm "%LOG%"
```

Comment: There is no such command, neither on my Windows 7 `cmd.exe` nor in any batch file command reference I could dig up in the last few minutes of googling. Are you sure it's not a custom executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if this is not Unix, `rm` is going to be a command to delete a file. For example, see http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/rm.1.asp or http://www.cygwin.com/

Answer (score 3):

rm is a commandlet in Windows Powershell.

> NAME:
>       Remove-Item
>
> SYNOPSIS:
>       Deletes the specified items.
>
> DESCRIPTION:
>       The Remove-Item cmdlet deletes one or more items. Because it is supported
>   by many providers, it can delete many
>   different types of items, including
>   files, directories, registry keys,
>   variables, aliases, and functions.

%LOG% is a variable defined in that batch file using 
set LOG="Something"
(NOTE: It is not a global Variable or alias)
So what it will do is delete the item pointed by variable LOG.

Comment: Also the batch file will be having a call to Powershell. It can be done simply by command powershell

Answer (score 2):

The `rm` is a command that's being run, rather than anything special for the batch file.  Does the system which ran this batch file include the [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) package?  That provides Windows / DOS versions of various standard unix utilities, including `rm` - which is the remove command - similar to `del` on such boxes.

Comment: Without knowing the system upon which the question poster's batch file was running - or indeed the rest of the batch file - it is not clear what the path may be on the system.  The FAQ for cygwin suggests that, for example, if you use it's provided desktop shotcut under windows it will automatically set up the path.  [This was a reply to a now deleted comment asking about whether rm would be on the path]

Answer (score 1):

%LOG% - variable that contain path to log file and that command remove it.

Answer (score 1):

`rm` is not a standard ms-dos command.  If you type it on the command line, what comes up?

perhaps it is short for `rmdir` (a synonym of `rd`) which removes the specified directory.

Answer (score 1):

`rm` is the *NIX version of  `del`

so its deleting `%LOG%`, unless it fails b/s its not a command on Windows. ( PowwerShell maybe)