# CMake not linking library files

Tags: c++, batch-file, cmake

I have a batch script which when run will simply call a cmake command to build a visual studio C++ project.  However, that project should have two references to two static libraries... yet, no matter what I try I can't seem to get my project to link the libraries correctly. Here's how my folder structure looks:

```
.
+-- build
|   +-- x64
|       +-- DebugStatic
|           +-- mylibA_static.lib
|           +-- mylibB_static.lib
+-- Include
+-- Source
+-- myproject
|   +-- Demo
|       +-- build
|       +-- cmake
|           +-- GenerateVS2015.bat
|       +-- CMakeLists.txt
|       +-- Demo.cpp
|       +-- stdafx.cpp
```

Now, I'm running the batch script from within the cmake folder inside the Demo project folder structure.  My batch script is as follows:

```
@echo off
set startingDir=%CD%

set basepath=%~dp0
set builddir=%basepath%\..\build
if not exist %builddir% (mkdir %builddir%)
cd %builddir%
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" .. %*

cd %startingDir%
```

Nothing too complicated.  Now, let's look at the CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT (Demo)

if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "MSVC")
  # using Visual Studio C++
  add_definitions(-DBUILD_DLL)
  SET(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} xmllite.lib")
  string(REGEX REPLACE "/bin/[^/]*$" "" VCINSTALLDIR "${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}")
  message(STATUS "Guessed MSVC directory: ${VCINSTALLDIR}")
endif()

SET(SRCS
  Demo.cpp
  stdafx.cpp
)

ADD_LIBRARY(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SRCS})
TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ../../Include)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}../../build/x64/DebugStatic/mylibA_static.lib ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}../../build/x64/DebugStatic/mylibB_static.lib)
```

Using this logic, wouldn't CMake build a Visual Studio C++ project called Demo.vcproj... and inside that project file would linked two libraries called mylibA_static.lib and mylibB_static.lib inside the references.  However, when I try this, I never get any sort of linked library.

Comment: Did you build that generated project? The script you provided only generates it.

Comment: What do you mean? Did I build mylibA_static.lib and mylibB_static.lib? Yes, I have the source code for those libraries too... but I figured since I already have the compiled libraries as .lib files... I was thinking it would be alot simpler if I could simply link those into the Demo project.  Is that possible? Or are you saying I should 'build' the Demo project?  If so, how do I do that using CMake? Because when I open the generated .vcproj demo project, I don't see any libraries linked in the project.

Comment: Trying to build the generated demo project fails.  It doesn't necessarily say why it fails, but I know it should be linking the libraries in the references section of the project... and those are not present, so I imagine it's because the libraries are properly linked.

Comment: Why doesn't it say? How are you building it?

Comment: In other words, show **exact** error message. BTW, in `target_include_directories` and `target_link_libraries` it is better to use **absolute** paths. You can refer to the source directory of the project with `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}`.

Comment: Ok.  So, after I run my batch script, it generates a .sln file inside my new build folder. I open that and select the Demo project and select 'build'. My output windows starts to feed statements like: `1>------ Build started: Project: Demo, Configuration: Release x64 ------` and `1>  Demo.cpp`. I've simplified my question so that it could be more manageable... so there's lots of .cpp files that are actually getting compiled. Then towards the end I see `1>  Generating Code...` and finally,  `========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========`.  That's it.

Answer (score 0):

First, in your batch script, you only generated the makefiles, but you didn't actually build the library. So I would suggest you add the line `make` after `cmake` and before `cd`.

Second, I would suggest you surround all your strings with double quotes, in order to be specific, and avoid confusion between `constants` and `variables`. Also, it is better to add additional slashes. So, change

`TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}../../build/x64/DebugStatic/mylibA_static.lib ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}../../build/x64/DebugStatic/mylibB_static.lib)`

to

`TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../build/x64/DebugStatic/mylibA_static.lib" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../build/x64/DebugStatic/mylibB_static.lib)"`.

As for the relative pathes, I think you are fine. But be careful when you use `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` and `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`. Here are some notes from [CMake Wiki](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables):

> CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR  this is the directory where the currently
>   processed CMakeLists.txt is located in
>
> CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR  this is the directory which contains the top-level
>   CMakeLists.txt, i.e. the top level source directory

Comment: Hmm.  Well, when I change all of my paths to include quotations and then run the batch script... it now only outputs a .sln file but not the .vcxproj file.  So, when I try to open the project, it fails to load.  Also, I added the line `make` after the cmake line but it doesn't appear to actually do anything (that I can tell).  Are there parameters I'm missing?

Comment: OK, then, add `rm -rf %builddir%` before the line `if not exist %builddir% (mkdir %builddir%)`. Basically, this will delete your old makefiles, and start over with a clean `build` folder.

Comment: `rm` doesn't appear to be a valid command.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585477/what-does-this-command-mean-in-batch.  Plus, wouldn't that command simply delete the build folder if it exists (which is then recreated in the very next line).  How would that help to regenerate the .vcxproj file?

Comment: My bad. I forgot this is Windows. So my point is, we need to delete all the older makefiles before we rebuild if something was wrong. If we don't delete them, `CMake` will think the files have already been created, and nothing will change. So I would suggest starting with a clean folder everytime you call `CMake`.

Comment: Well, I had been manually deleting the build folder before I ran the batch script... although I should totally automate that (you're right).  But, still I don't think that really solves my problem.  I still only get a .sln file instead of a .vcxproj file. And I'm not sure the libraries are linked either because I can't really open the project file.

Comment: Okay.... I'm a little confused right now. Since you are building a shared library, isn't it `*.DLL`? `*.vcxproj` and `*.sln` basically project files, right? Look into your `build` folder, and see whether there is a `*.DLL` file.

Comment: Ok, once I run the batch script here's what I get in my build folder.  There's a folder called CMakeFiles.  Then, there is an ALL_BUILD.vcxproj and ALL_BUILD.vxcproj.filters file.  There's the CMakeCache.txt file.  There's the ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj and ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj.filters files.  Finally, there is a Demo.sln file.  However, there is no Demo.vcxproj file or Demo.dll file.  I have included the `make` line after the `cmake...` line per your suggestions.  But, it doesn't seem to build the .dll or vcxproj files.

Comment: Ok. I guess we are getting into some unexpected problems here. Do you mind sharing the code to me. So I'd like to check it on my Mac.